# Using pyserial to interface with a power supply

Tags: python, pyserial, hardware-interface, hardware

I am using a RS-232 to USB converter to connect my Agilent E3640A to my laptop. I am trying to return the manufacture's name using the command "*IDN" as stated in their manual. When i try to read the line, I get an empty string. I am also just having trouble putting the device in remote mode. Here is the link to their manual : https://all-guidesbox.com/model/agilent-technologies/e3640a.html

It seems that my power supply is not properly connected to my PC according to Keysight Connection Helper. It produces this error code:

```
! VI_ERROR_TMO: A timeout occurred
Visa ErrorCode: 0xBFFF0015 (-1073807339)
 ! Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

My Code:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.timeout = 20
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM8'
print('Connected to ' + ser.name)
ser.open()
ser.reset_input_buffer()
ser.reset_output_buffer()
#ser.write('SYST:INT{RS232}'.encode('utf-8'))
ser.write(b'SYST:REM')
ser.flush()
ser.write('*IDN?'.encode('utf-8'))
ser.flush()
print(ser.readline())
```

Actual Output:

```
Connected to COM8
b''
```

Desired Output:

```
Connected to COM8
‘‘Agilent Technologies,E3640A,0,X.X-Y.Y-Z.Z’’
```

Comment: You need to terminate your command with a newline character (`\n`).

Comment: So I just tried that: ser.write('*IDN?\n'.encode('utf-8')).             ser.write(b'SYST:REM\n').         I still got the same output

Comment: Double check that 9600 is the correct baud rate - it can be changed from the front panel.  Sorry, no other ideas.

Comment: can you use any program like hyperterm or minicom and first validate that you can send commands manually

Comment: I can confirm that 9600 is the correct baud rate. I am not familiar with hyperterm or minicom

Comment: I just updated my question with a just discovered error message

Comment: Until you can demonstrate that this works with a terminal program, it's really premature to be treating it as a programming problem.  Time to learn about minicom or hyperterm or screen or whatever you like.

Comment: Turns out I just had a bad cable. Do I just delete this post now?